# How can I determine in my app that a user has purchased a Play Pass subscription?

Tags: android, kotlin, subscription, play-billing-library

I want to count how many users have an active Play Pass Subscription. Is it possible to determine this if my application does not have Play Pass enabled?

I tried to get this information from BillingClient, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
suspend fun checkPlayPassSubscription(packageName: String, purchaseToken: String, accessToken: String): Boolean {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://play.googleapis.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(PlayDeveloperApiService::class.java)
    val response = service.getSubscriptionStatus(packageName, purchaseToken, accessToken)

    return if (response.isSuccessful) {
        // try to check the response for the subscription status
             true
    } else {
        // Handle error
        false
    }
}
```